# Relationship with Tables MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have some small issue with relationships with tables as below:

I have created a login and registration script which has the following

```
table name: members:
fields: member_id, firstname, lastname, login, password
```

Now i have made another table with this

```
table name: phone
fields: member_id, phoneid, name, number, prefix, time,total
```

I want to make a form whereby a admin can select the name of the client from a drop down list, and then add a record such as the number called, number prefix, total time and the amount for that period.

I dont know how to do this, please help me by creating a script or help me how to go about this.

So all the time a admin makes a form on Client A it gets added to a new row on the phone table, then i will just add a call script on the client side where they can see all the records that they have done.

Thanks please assist.

Regards

Comment: seeing this as 1:n relationship, you need to add `member_id` to you phone table

Comment: @knittl i have added the member_id to the phone table.

Please assist forward.

Answer (score 0):

Your db design seems fundamentally flawed - the is no association between the members and the phone_numbers tables. Add a FK (member_id) to phone_numbers table.

Regards creating the front-end, there are quite a lot of libraries that have data stores (we use ExtJS), and upon flushing the store you can do the persistence with php.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello James, thanks for your reply.

I am not that good with MySQL is it possible you can create for me a small database and php script to do that job, i will be highly appreciated.

I dont really know how to make the relationships, i am using PHPmyADMIN to do the work for the MySQL

Thanks & Regards